# Having immense trouble with epstopdf

Tags: pdftex, eps, epstopdf

I am using TeXstudio on Windows.
My LaTeX file location is in C:/Users/Documents
My image is in the same location.

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt,3p]{elsarticle}
\newif\ifpdf
\ifx\pdfoutput\undefined
\pdffalse
\else
   \pdfoutput=1
   \pdftrue
\fi
\ifpdf
   \usepackage{graphicx}
   \usepackage{epstopdf}
   \DeclareGraphicsRule{.eps}{pdf}{.pdf}{`epstopdf #1}
   \pdfcompresslevel=9
\else
   \usepackage{graphicx}
\fi

    \usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amscd,amsmath,enumerate,verbatim,calc,float,wrapfig}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\epstopdfsetup{suffix=}
\begin{document}
\section{intro}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics{Figure 2.eps}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The log file says:

```
! Package pdftex.def Error: File `Figure 2.pdf' not found: using draft setting.
LaTeX Warning: File `Figure 2.eps' not found on input line 59.

Package epstopdf Info: Source file: <Figure 2.eps>
(epstopdf)                    date: 2018-09-11 07:12:24
(epstopdf)                    size: 1751510 bytes
(epstopdf)             Output file: <Figure 2.pdf>
(epstopdf)             Command: <epstopdf Figure 2.eps>
(epstopdf)             \includegraphics on input line 59.
runsystem(epstopdf Figure 2.eps)...executed.

Package epstopdf Info: Result file: <Figure 2.pdf>.

! Package pdftex.def Error: File `Figure 2.pdf' not found: using draft setting.

See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.59 \includegraphics{Figure 2.eps}
Overfull \hbox (2.61108pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
```

Now
If I just say \includegraphics{Figure 1} without eps extension, this is the log file:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `Figure 2' not found.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.59 \includegraphics{Figure 2}

I could not locate the file with any of these extensions:
.pdf,.png,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PDF,.PNG,.JPG,.JPEG,.JBIG2,.JB2,.eps,.ep
s
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.


Overfull \hbox (2.61108pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
```

If I use outdir in epstopdfsetup, how exactly do I write it with respect to my file location?
Is there a problem with my file location? BOth image and source file are in same folder.

Comment: Remove the extension from your file name (so `\includegraphics{Figure 2}`. At the same time: a modern TeX system will automatically do all of the necessary set up. You should not need any of that `\ifpdf` stuff, but rather just load `graphicx`.

Comment: In general it is not a good idea to use spaces in filenames.

Comment: Oh, BTW: spaces in file names are _bad_ news!

Comment: Remove all this \newif\ifpdf and \ifx\pdfoutput\undefined stuff and load the ifpdf package instead.

Comment: It worked after removing spaces thank you so much!

Comment: you should be able to replace all of `\newif\ifpdf
\ifx\pdfoutput\undefined
\pdffalse
\else
   \pdfoutput=1
   \pdftrue
\fi
\ifpdf
   \usepackage{graphicx}
   \usepackage{epstopdf}
   \DeclareGraphicsRule{.eps}{pdf}{.pdf}{\`epstopdf #1}
   \pdfcompresslevel=9
\else
   \usepackage{graphicx}
\fi`   by simply `\usepackage{graphicx}`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in the comments